# Ways to overcome the limitation of concurrent operations in SQL Database(azure)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, federation

My application is using windows azure and SQL Database(Azure). In near future we will be having traffic for our SQL Database near to 50,000 transactions/min. I am using 5GB Web database. 
Now there is a limit of 400 concurrent operations per partition in SQL Database:[Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1541.windows-azure-sql-database-connection-management-en-us.aspx#Limits_Table)

What are the possible ways to overcome this limitation? At the moment the best solution i can think of is federation. Which are the other ways? And which one is the best?
**EDIT :** Transactions will be write only. We are collecting performance data from our client systems every 5 seconds which are sent to our REST API which eventually inserts data to SQL Database. So no UI and caching is out of question.

Comment: A write-only database is not terribly useful. Surely you'll have some reads. You'll also need to have deletes on the scale as your writes, or your database will fill up pretty quickly. 

Unless your goal is truly just storing all that data you may want to consider preprocessing it, perhaps with something like StreamInsight, and storing a summary of it instead.

Comment: It is not a write-only database. But amount of reads is negligible. And yes the data is deleted every 5 mins, it is consolidated. So only concern is being able to write the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Federations in Windows Azure SQL Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597452.aspx) is one option. But I prefer offloading the heavy work to different data store like Table Storage, Blobs or Queues since they were built to handle a heavy load and they partition much easier. Combine this with good caching and you might overcome this limitation with ease.

Imagine your site has a top 10 products list on your home page and you have 100,000 visitors / day. One option would be to query SQL Azure each time, but this could cause a heavy load on SQL Azure. But you could have a worker process running every 24 hour for example and calculating the top 10 products at that time, and save them in Table Storage (you could make a few partitions in that table containing the top 10 per country, per category, ...). You could see this as a pre-generated view. Each time you want to show the top 10 products you would query the items from Table Storage (a specific partition in a table) which scales much better. Add some ASP.NET caching there and you'll have a very reliable system.

That was it for reading data. But I imagine you'll also be expecting some user input, where a user can create an order, send messages, ... There again, if you're expecting a heavy load SQL Azure might not be your best option to interact with directly (seen the limitations). Using queues between your front end and your back end might be a better solution.

When your users place an order you can write a message to a queue (Storage Queue or Service Bus Queue). A worker will pick up this message, and create a record in the table for that order with the time, product count and maybe even a status (like processing) that you would show in the user's orders screen. Once you've done this you have all the time you need to do finish the order and once you finished it you save the end result in SQL Azure (and you update the order record in table storage). Saving the end result in SQL Azure will still make it possible to use reporting etc...

This will have a big impact on your application. An other solution would be to host SQL Server yourself in a Virtual Machine, but note that this is still in CTP: [Provisioning a SQL Server Virtual Machine on Windows Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/windows/common-tasks/install-sql-server/)

Comment: Thanks! will go with azure table storage.

Answer (score 2):

Federations is of course an option because it's a shared nothing infrastructure. However you may want to first reflect on why you need such a high volume of transactions. Are your transactions going to be mostly read or write operations? Do you have a middle tier in place? The techniques available differ for write and read operations. Here are a few techniques you can use to help you minimize the number of transactions per second on a SQL Database instance when you have a middle tier in place:

- Caching (as mentioned by Sandrino)
- Set-based transactions
- Eventual consistency

Caching is important when your system is trying to provide data to a consumer, in a read scenario (or denormalization). I won't expand on caching other than to say you have serious pros and cons to consider, such as data freshness and synchronization issues across nodes. The other two techniques below are for writes.

Set-based transactions are absolutely crutial in a database system. If your system inserts lots of records every second for example, you would place the insert requests in a queue for example, then process the queue on a separate thread, then pool ten or twenty requests into a single database call. This requires asynchronous processing and set based operations on the database. But in the end groupping records for processing is one of the keys to success in SQL Database. We are designing a system right now that would make well above 500 transactions per second if it weren't for implementing a similar pattern.

Eventual consistency is another important concept, and I alluded to it previously with the set-based approach. Eventual consistency means that the database may not contain all the records right now, and that it may take some time for all the records to be available. But eventually, the records will make it. The example I provided above (with the queue) implements both a set-based operation and an eventual consistency pattern.